# Angular Directive not applying changes made in code on refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have a pretty basic directive that I include on my base cshtml file that is shown when resolves for a route are loading and then hidden once the resolves are loaded. It works great:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.directives.resolveLoader', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])
        .directive('resolveLoader', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$log', function ($root, $timeout, $log) {
            return {
                replace: true,
                restrict: 'E',
                template: '<div id="resolve-loader">' +
                              '<i class="fa fa-5x fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch emerald-font"></i>' + 
                              '<h3>Loading</h3>' + 
                          '</div>',
                link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                    $root.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
                        $log.info('app.directives.resolveLoader(): Showing resolve-loader');
                        $timeout(function () {
                            ele.removeClass('ng-hide');
                        });
                    });

                    $root.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
                        $log.info('app.directives.resolveLoader(): Hiding resolve-loader');
                        ele.addClass('ng-hide');
                        $log.info('app.directives.resolveLoader(): ' + ele.hasClass('ng-hide'));
                    })
                }
            }
        }]);
})();
```

Every time I go to a new route in my application that has resolves on it, I see this in my console:

```
app.directives.resolveLoader(): Showing resolve-loader
app.directives.resolveLoader(): Hiding resolve-loader
app.directives.resolveLoader(): true
```

I see the same thing if I refresh a page (<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), however it never actually hides the element and I don't see the `ng-hide` class being applied to the element in the DOM.

Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Needed to wrap the `ele.hideClass()` call in a $timeout function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was wrapping the `ele.addClass()` in a $timeout function, like so:

```
                $root.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
                    $log.info('app.directives.resolveLoader(): Hiding resolve-loader');
                    $timeout(function () {
                        ele.addClass('ng-hide');
                    });
                })
```